# no me insertar datos en base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

tengo un problema, cuando realizo la inserción de datos en la "db" no me sale error, pero no me inserta ningun dato en la misma, esto desde el server [www.000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com). ahora cuando corro la misma pagina php y la misma db mysql en mi localhost con xampp me lo carga perfecto.

aca dejo la pagina con las variables a cargar

```
<?php 
include "funcion/conexion.php";
require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; 

date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Cordoba');
$time = time();
$clientId = '****';
$clientSecret = '****';
$redirect = 'https://eltour2021.000webhostapp.com/index.php';

$api = new Iamstuartwilson\StravaApi($clientId, $clientSecret);

$gettoken =  $db->query("SELECT * FROM ciclistas");
$restoken = $gettoken->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($restoken as $key => $value) {
    
    $ciclista = $value->nombre;
    $existingAccessToken = $value->access_token; // $token del código anterior
    $expires = $value->expires_at;
    $refreshToken = $value->refresh_token;

if ($expires > $time){

  $api->setAccessToken($existingAccessToken, $refreshToken, $expires);
  }else{
  $new = $api->tokenExchangeRefresh($refreshToken);

  $newaccessToken = $new->access_token;
  $newrefreshToken = $new->refresh_token;
  $newexpiresAt = $new->expires_at;
  $api->setAccessToken($newaccessToken, $newrefreshToken, $newexpiresAt);
}

$activuser = $api->get('athlete/activities',['after' => 1609459338,'before' => 1614556558]);

foreach ($activuser as $key => $value) {
    
    $distancia = $value->distance/1000;
    $desnivel = $value->total_elevation_gain; 
    $fecha = $value->start_date_local; 
    $idstrava = $value->id; 
    $name = $value->name; 
    $type = $value->type;
    $ciclistaid = $value->athlete->id; 

if ($type == 'Ride') {

    $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO actividades (distancia,desnivel,fecha,idstrava,name,ciclistaid)) VALUES  (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $res = $sql->execute([$distancia,$desnivel,$fecha,$idstrava,$name,$ciclistaid]);
     if($res){
                    echo 'Datos ingresados';
                }
                else{
                    echo 'Datos NO Ingresados';
                }
                $sql= null;
    


// echo "<pre>";
// echo 'distancia: ';print_r($distancia);echo "<br>";
// echo 'desnivel: ';print_r($desnivel);echo "<br>";
// echo 'fecha: ';print_r($fecha);echo "<br>";
// echo 'ciclista: ';print_r($ciclista);echo "<br>";
// // echo 'ciclistaid: ';print_r($ciclistaid);echo "<br>";
// echo 'nombre actividad: ';print_r($name);echo "<br>";
// echo 'type: ';print_r($type);echo "<br>";
// echo 'idstrava: ';print_r($idstrava);echo "<br>";
// echo "</pre>";
}
}
}

// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($activuser);
// echo "</pre>";

// $clubactiv = $api->get('clubs/525846/activities');
// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($clubactiv);
// echo "</pre>";

$sql = $db->query("SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y/%m/%d a las %H:%i') as fecha FROM actividades,ciclistas where actividades.ciclistaid=ciclistas.strava ORDER BY fecha DESC, distancia DESC");
$resact = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<?php include ("funcion/head.php");?>
<body>
    <?php include ("funcion/header.php");?>
<!-- about breadcrumb -->
<section class="w3l-about-breadcrumb">
  <div class="breadcrumb-bg breadcrumb-bg-about py-5">
      <div class="container pt-lg-5 pt-md-3 p-lg-4 pb-md-3 my-lg-5">
          <ul class="breadcrumbs-custom-path mt-5 pt-lg-5 text-center">
              <li><a href="index.php" class="fa fa-home inner-home" aria-hidden="true"></a></li>
              <li class="active"><span class="fa fa-arrow-right mx-2" aria-hidden="true"></span> Actividades </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- //about breadcrumb -->
<section class="w3l-content-6 py-5">
  <div class="container py-md-5" style="overflow-x:scroll">
    <!-- /content-6-section -->
    <div class="content-6-mian text-center">
      <h3 class="w3l-hnytitle mb-5">Actividades</h3>
      <div class="content-info-in row">
        <table class="table table-responsive table-dark table-striped">
          <tr>
            <th>Ciclista</th>
            <th>Distancia Recorrida</th>
            <th>Desnivel Positivo</th>
            <th>Fecha Realizada</th>
            <th>Nombre Actividad</th>
            <th>Accion</th>
          </tr>
          <?php foreach ($resact as $key => $value) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $value->nombre;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->distancia;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->desnivel;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->fecha;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->name;?></td>
            <td>
              <a href="actividad_edit.php?id=<?php echo $value->idactividad;?>" class="btn btn-large btn-warning" ><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>
              <a href="actividad_del.php?id=<?php echo $value->idactividad;?>" class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="return confirmation()"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
 <!-- //content-6-section -->
<?php include ("funcion/footer.php");?>

</body>

</html>
```

estas es la base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi conexion

```
$pass = '****';
$user = 'id15833229_****';
$nombredb = 'id15833229_tourcomar';

try{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$nombredb,$user,$pass);

}catch (Exception $e){
    echo "error de conexion ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Repito, cuando lo hago en mi localhost me funciona ok, pero desde el servidor [www.000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com) no me carga los daatos en la base de datos, tampoco me arroja error.
Sera porque son muchos datos, ya que es un array? o estoy poniendo algo mal en el codigo?

muchas gracias
saludos

Comment: El código va como texto por favor

Comment: Y censura las claves y esas cosas...

Comment: Revisa el nombre de la base de datos, por lo general los hosting anteponen un prefijo `prefijo_tuBaseDeDatos` y ese nombre debes cambiar en donde haces la conexión.

Comment: Es necesario siempre controlar tu código. Para empezar, verifica si hay conexión o no, poniendo esto antes de empezar a usar el objeto de conexión: `if ($db) { $gettoken =  $db->query("SELECT * FROM ciclistas"); /*Y todo el resto de tu código*/ } else { echo "NO HAY CONEXIÓN"; }`  Si en pantalla ves `NO HAY CONEXIÓN` entonces ya tienes una etapa depurada, y deberás revisar tus credenciales y demás y por qué no está conectado. En una segunda etapa, podrás depurar el resultado de la consulta SQL. Implementa ese primer control y dinos qué ha pasado.

Comment: No sale error... revisaste los logs de PHP? Y lo otro: Lo que pasa por poner el código de la conexión como imagen. Todos estamos viendo tus credenciales. Yo lo pondría como texto y poniendo datos falsos allí.

Comment: Probe agregando el if y si hay conexión a la db, es mas me trae los datos del query que consulto, pero sigue sin insertarme los datos

Comment: Podría estar ocurriendo algún error en la inserción (de sintaxis en la sentencia SQL, de clave duplicada, violación de alguna restricción), por tanto, tienes que controlar también eso, haciendo uso de `errorInfo()`  al menos en fase de desarrollo, para determinar el error exacto y corregirlo. Significa hacer algo así en la inserción: `if ( $sql && $res = $sql->execute([AQUI-TODAS-LAS-VARIABLES]) )  { /*No hay error ni de preparación ni de ejecución, conviene verificar el valor de rowCount()*/ } else { /*Hay error, en fase de desarrollo puedes poner algo como esto*/ var_dump($db->errorInfo();}`

Comment: no te entendi como hacer el if?

Comment: hola, sigo sin poder saber cual es el problema, alguno me pude dar una mano? gracias